# Cannot run a simple android application after updating the sdk

Tags: android

Hi I have updated my sdk to api level 21 and i am getting many errors from then. My simple application which didnt give any kind of errors before started giving me run time exceptions.
Here is my mainactivity.java class:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem shareItem=menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
    ShareActionProvider m=(ShareActionProvider)MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);
    m.setShareIntent(getDefaultIntent());
    return true;
}

private Intent getDefaultIntent() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    return intent;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

My Manifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

My main.xml:

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

   <item
       android:id="@+id/action_share"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share"
       android:orderInCategory="100"
       android:title="@string/action_share"
       app:showAsAction="always"
       app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>
   </menu>
```

When i run this simple application i get the following errors:

```
10-29 03:08:48.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1481): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-29 03:08:48.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1481): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate            activity ComponentInfo 
com.example.myfirstapp.com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity
10-29 03:08:48.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
10-29 03:08:48.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
10-29 03:08:48.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
10-29 03:08:48.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
10-29 03:08:48.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-29 03:08:48.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-29 03:08:48.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-29 03:08:48.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-29 03:08:48.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-29 03:08:48.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-29 03:08:48.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-29 03:08:48.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-29 03:08:48.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1481): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.myfirstapp.com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity
10-29 03:08:48.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
10-29 03:08:48.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
10-29 03:08:48.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
10-29 03:08:48.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
10-29 03:08:48.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
10-29 03:08:48.153: E/AndroidRuntime(1481):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see your class is `com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity` but program can't found `com.example.myfirstapp.com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity` as it has doubled your package name.

in `AndroidManifest.xml` try to put main class with package name instead of `.MainActivity`. Does it work then?

```
<application>
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Can anyone suggest me any options?